# Как распарсить ASN1 структуру с тегом 0xA0 в Go?

Tags: golang

При попытке распарсить ASN1 структуру, которая начинается с тега 0xA0 выдает ошибку:

```
Failed to decode ASN.1 structure:asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:2 tag:0 length:3 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false}
```

Однако онлайн парсер спокойно обрабатывает эту структуру

[image: скриншот с парсера]

Код:

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/asn1"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Field1 int `asn1:"tag:0"`
}

func main() {
    data := []byte{0xA0, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01}

    var myStruct MyStruct
    _, err := asn1.Unmarshal(data, &myStruct)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to decode ASN.1 structure:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Field1:", myStruct.Field1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Байты, которые вы привели, не задают структуру `SEQUENCE OF`: закодированная структура начинается с `0x10` или `0x30`. В вашем случае последовательность начинается с `0xA0` - это контекстно-зависимый тег, который нужно парсить исходя из знания контекста.

Как-то вы должны были догадаться, что это целое число, и парсить как число, а не как структуру. В пакете `encoding/asn1` есть функция `UnmarshalWithParams`, которой можно подсказать контекст для разбора DER-строки. В вашем случае надо сообщить, что это явно заданное контекстно-зависимое поле целого типа с тегом `0`: `"explicit,tag:0"`. То есть в исходной ASN.1 спецификации оно было описано как

```
Field1  [0]  INTEGER
```

Поэтому надо передавать в качестве приёмника распарсенного значения указатель на целое: `&myStruct.Field1`

```go
package main

import (
    "encoding/asn1"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Field1 int `asn1:"tag:0"`
}
func main() {
    data := []byte{0xA0, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01}

    var myStruct MyStruct
    _, err := asn1.UnmarshalWithParams(data, &myStruct.Field1, "explicit,tag:0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to decode ASN.1 structure:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Field1:", myStruct.Field1)
}
```

Результат: https://go.dev/play/p/61JKMX2UdVq

```
Field1: 1
```